# Return Majority from PostGIS function ST_SummaryStatsAgg()

Tags: postgis, spatial-statistics, raster-functions, postgresql-10

The mentioned [function](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SummaryStatsAgg.html)

> Returns summarystats consisting of count, sum, mean, stddev, min, max for a given raster band of a raster or raster coverage.

I have an image of land cover classes (a discrete dataset), returning the mean does not make much sense since there are only classes (essentially integer numbers).

The procedure is like this: the image is clipped (using ST_clip) to the extent of a polygon (representing multiple farm fields) and then the dominant (majority) land cover class should be determined.

**Question**

- How to get the majority from the `ST_SummaryStatsAgg()` function directly?

or

- How to modify `ST_SummaryStatsAgg()` to calculate the majority?

or

- Is there another function/procedure that gives me the result that I want?

Comment: When you say majority, do you mean the class with the maximum count ? What happens if two of them share the same count (just to make sure nothing breaks in my code idea..)

Comment: @GHRF yes, the class with the maximum count. Two classes with the same count: random would be fine, or the class that reached maximum first would also be an option. what's your idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (assuming you have two tables : one with the polygons and an id, one with the raster which contains their class as an attribute)

```
With stats as (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        geom, 
        (ST_SummaryStatsAgg(ST_Clip(rast, geom), 1, true)).count, 
        class
    FROM rasters, polygons
    GROUP BY id, geom, class)
SELECT distinct on (count)
    id, geom, count, class
FROM stats
WHERE count = (select max(count) from stats)
ORDER BY count, id, class;
```

The "distinct on (count)" makes sure that only one line is returned if several classes are the majority. Since we're ordering by class, it will take the first one alphabetically. There might be too many items in my GROUP BY clause but I'm never sure how much is too much and would rather be safe than sorry. Hope this works/helps !

Comment: Seems like a good answer, though not sure about group by id, whixh I think will just deaggregate everything.

Comment: Well, here the id are linked to the polygons, not the rasters. Perhaps grouping by id and geom is redundant, though.

Comment: Good point, id and geom refer to the same entitity, so grouping by both doesn't matter.