# Get majority value of raster data inside polygon using PostGIS

Tags: raster-calculator, postgis-2.0, postgis-raster

We have imported a tiff with landcover data into PostGIS as a raster table.
We also have a polygon table with provinces.

I'm trying to get the majority of the landcover in each province.
But can't get it to work. I already looked at [Return Majority from PostGIS function ST_SummaryStatsAgg()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281028/return-majority-from-postgis-function-st-summarystatsagg) and we are using `ST_SummaryStatsAgg()` already with other raster data. But we are stuck with the Majority calculation.

The problem we have with the mentioned link is that we don't have the class attribute nor do we know how to create it from the raster data.

Answer (score -2):

My experience is that PostGIS is less suitable for calculating with raster data.

You could try using the GeoDMS, open source software for modelling with (large) geo datasets (both vector and raster). More information on wiki.objectvision.nl

With a simple script you can relate your polygon vector dataset to the raster data and count the number of landcover cells per type in the provinces.